# Borwein’s algorithm for the calculation of Pi in Fortran is converging too fast

Tags: fortran, pi

The following implementation of [Borwein’s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein%27s_algorithm) with quartic convergence in Fortran admittedly calculates Pi, but converges simply too fast. In theory, `a` converges quartically to 1/π. On each iteration, the number of correct digits is therefore quadrupled.

```
! pi.f90
program main
    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: real128
    implicit none
    real(kind=real128), parameter :: CONST_PI = acos(-1._real128)
    real(kind=real128)            :: pi
    integer                       :: i

    do i = 1, 10
        pi = borwein(i)
        print '("Pi (n = ", i3, "): ", f0.100)', i, pi
    end do

    print '("Pi:", 11x, f0.100)', CONST_PI
contains
    function borwein(n) result(pi)
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        real(kind=real128)  :: pi
        real(kind=real128)  :: a, y
        integer             :: i

        y = sqrt(2._real128) - 1
        a = 2 * (sqrt(2._real128) - 1)**2

        do i = 1, n
            y = (1 - (1 - y**4)**.25_real128) / (1 + (1 - y**4)**.25_real128)
            a = a * (1 + y)**4 - 2**(2 * (i - 1) + 3) * y * (1 + y + y**2)
        end do

        pi = 1 / a
    end function borwein
end program main
```

But after the second iteration, the value of Pi does not change anymore, as one can see for the first 100 digits:

```
$ gfortran -o pi pi.f90
$ ./pi
Pi (n =   1): 3.1415926462135422821493444319826910539597974491424025615960346875056357837663334464650688460096716881
Pi (n =   2): 3.1415926535897932384626433832795024122930792206901249618089158148888330110426458929850923595950007439
Pi (n =   3): 3.1415926535897932384626433832795024122930792206901249618089158148888330110426458929850923595950007439
Pi (n =   4): 3.1415926535897932384626433832795024122930792206901249618089158148888330110426458929850923595950007439
Pi (n =   5): 3.1415926535897932384626433832795024122930792206901249618089158148888330110426458929850923595950007439
Pi (n =   6): 3.1415926535897932384626433832795024122930792206901249618089158148888330110426458929850923595950007439
Pi (n =   7): 3.1415926535897932384626433832795024122930792206901249618089158148888330110426458929850923595950007439
Pi (n =   8): 3.1415926535897932384626433832795024122930792206901249618089158148888330110426458929850923595950007439
Pi (n =   9): 3.1415926535897932384626433832795024122930792206901249618089158148888330110426458929850923595950007439
Pi (n =  10): 3.1415926535897932384626433832795024122930792206901249618089158148888330110426458929850923595950007439
Pi:           3.1415926535897932384626433832795027974790680981372955730045043318742967186629755360627314075827598572
```

(The last output is the correct value of Pi for comparison.)

Is there an error in the implementation? I’m not sure, if `real128` precision is always kept.

Comment: As far as I know, the range quals that of binary128, i.e., 10^-4965 to 10^4932. That makes ~34 digits, if I’m not wrong…

Comment: Wondering, whether someone ever treated the cancellation in term (1-x^4): you need four time the precision of the result! While 1-(1-x^4)^0,25 if very stable, O(x^4).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the second iteration you have converged to as many digits as real128 can support:

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat pi2.f90
Program pi2

  Use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: real128

  Implicit None

  Real( real128 ) :: pi

  pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795024122930792206901249618089158148888330110426458929850923595950007439_real128

  Write( *, '( f0.100 )' ) pi
  Write( *, '( f0.100 )' ) Nearest( pi, +1.0_real128 )
  Write( *, '( f0.100 )' ) Abs( acos(-1._real128) - Nearest( pi, +1.0_real128 ) )



End Program pi2
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all pi2.f90 
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
3.1415926535897932384626433832795024122930792206901249618089158148888330110426458929850923595950007439
3.1415926535897932384626433832795027974790680981372955730045043318742967186629755360627314075827598572
.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
ian@eris:~/work/stack$
```

Thus the further iterations show no change as it is already as accurate as it can be

Comment: Is there any way in Fortran to store more digits?

Comment: The Fortran language itself requires only single and double precision. A compiler may support additional real kinds, and quad precision is common. Nothing after that, though. There are some multi-precision libraries out there, but using them will be even slower. These libraries also probably lack the trigonometric functions you are using.

What is the point of this exercise?

Comment: One example is the high-precision library: https://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbsoftware/.   As the previous comment stated, outside of the Fortran language.

Comment: Another one https://dmsmith.lmu.build/ (which supports trigonometric functions).

Comment: I just wanted to implement a function that uses ```real128```.

Comment: If that's the case you've done it consistently and haven't lost any precision through mixing kinds of real